# Pie chart with ggplot2 using data from read.csv2

Tags: r

I am trying to create a pie chart with ggplot. I want to show how many hours I use for diffrent tasks at work everyday.

[image]

```
# Libraries
library(ggplot2)
library(tidyverse) # function "%>%"

# 1. Read data (semicolon separated)
res = read.csv2(text = "Activity;No_of_Hours
Work;3
Lunch;1
Meetings;2
Talking;1")

# 2. Print table
df <- as.data.frame(res)
df

# 3. Plot Pie chart
res %>% ggplot(aes(x="",           # we leave x blank with ""
                       y= Activity, 
                       fill=No_of_Hours)) +
    geom_bar(stat="identity") +
  coord_polar("y", start=0) +
  theme_classic()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can calculate the y position of labels with `coord_polar` and plot them with `geom_text`

```
df <- df %>% 
  arrange(desc(Activity)) %>%
  mutate(prop = No_of_Hours / sum(df$No_of_Hours) *100) %>%
  mutate(ypos = cumsum(prop)- 0.5*prop )
# 3. Plot Pie chart

ggplot(df, aes(x="", y=prop, fill=Activity)) +
  geom_bar(stat="identity", width=1, color="white") +
  coord_polar("y", start=0) +
  theme_void() + 
  geom_text(aes(y = ypos, label = No_of_Hours), color = "white", size=6)
```

which give you:

[image]

Or more similar to your example (but IMHO less informative):

```
ggplot(df, aes(x="", y=prop, fill=No_of_Hours)) +
  geom_bar(stat="identity", width=1, color="white") +
  coord_polar("y", start=0) +
  theme_void() + 
  geom_text(aes(y = ypos, label =Activity ), color = "white", size=6)
```

which give you:

[image]